# Correct way to update form states in React?

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, react-native, create-react-app

So I'm having a go at my first React app using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app), and I'm trying to make a multi-stage form based on [this](https://github.com/tommymarshall/react-multi-step-form) GitHub project. In particular the [AccountFields](https://github.com/tommymarshall/react-multi-step-form/blob/master/src/javascript/components/Registration.jsx) and [Registration](https://github.com/tommymarshall/react-multi-step-form/blob/master/src/javascript/components/AccountFields.jsx) parts.

That project seems to have been written in a much older version of React, so I've had to try and update it - and this is what I have so far:

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Activity from './Activity';

var stage1Values = {
    activity_name : "test"
};

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            step: 1
        };
    };

    render() {
        switch (this.state) {
            case 1:
                return <Activity fieldValues={stage1Values} />;
        }
    };

    saveStage1Values(activity_name) {
        stage1Values.activity_name = activity_name;
    };

    nextStep() {
        this.setState({
          step : this.state.step + 1
        })
    };
}

export default App;
```

Activity.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Activity extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <div>
                    <label>Activity Name</label>
                    <input type="text" ref="activity_name" defaultValue={this.props.stage1Values} />
                    <button onClick={this.nextStep}>Save &amp; Continue</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    };

    nextStep(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        // Get values via this.refs
        this.props.saveStage1Values(this.refs.activity_name.getDOMNode().value);
        this.props.nextStep();
    }
}

export default Activity;
```

I've looked at a number of examples, and this seems to be the right approach to store the current state (to allow users to go back and forth between different parts of the form), and to then store the values from this stage. When I click the `Save & Continue` button, I get an error saying `Cannot read property 'props' of null`. I mean obviously this means `this` is null, but I'm unsure of how to fix it.

Am I approaching this the wrong way? Every example I find seems to have a completely different implementation. I come from an Apache-based background, so this approach in general I find very unusual!

Comment: try `this.nextProps.bind(this)`. For detail http://egorsmirnov.me/2015/08/16/react-and-es6-part3.html

Comment: `<button onClick={this.nextStep}>Save &amp; Continue</button>` in `Activity.js`

Answer (score 0):

the this in nextStep isn't pointing to Activity and just do like this

```
<button onClick={()=>this.nextStep()}>Save &amp; Continue</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind *this* to *nextStep* function:

```
<button onClick={this.nextStep.bind(this)}>Save &amp; Continue</button>
```

Or in the constructor:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.nextSteps = this.nextSteps.bind(this);
}
```